# Is the a in artistically, logically, etc. silent?

Tags: pronunciation

[Some](https://englishlikeanative.co.uk/blog/words-with-silent-letters/) websites claim,

> A is silent when it comes before ‘lly’ – artistically, logically, musically, naturally, romantically, stoically.

Isn't there (at least) a (lightly) pronounced ə in each case?

Does any English speaker ever pronounce the above words as *artisticly*, *logicly*, *musicly*, *naturly*, *romanticly*, and *stoicly*?

Comment: It really depends on how someone pronounces it. Either is fine.

Comment: [In the UK] The _c_ and the _l_ are often - perhaps mostly - as close together as they are in the word _clam_, But in _naturally_ it's often the _u_ that gets elided: _nat'rally_.

Comment: If only there was some publication that tells us how words are pronounced. [Merriam-Webster hedges its bets](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logically) with (in their own strange pronunciation format) *ˈlä-ji-k(ə-)lē*.

Comment: For American English, there's [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater) from M-W, which they refuse to use in their other dictionaries, because they think Americans are too dumb to learn IPA. I am sorry to say that they're probly correct in that.

Comment: Also, you should stop thinking of letters being silent. All letters are silent; letters occur in writing, not speech. Speech is sounds, not spelling.

Comment: For most of them, lots of people pronounce them *artisticly, logicly, musicly, romanticly, and stoicly*  But for [*naturally*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/naturally?q=naturally), if we're not using the four-syllable pronunciation, we usually delete the second syllable rather than the third, getting the pronunciation /ˈnætʃrəli/.

Comment: Slight off-topic, but seeing 'publically' in print really annoys me.

Answer (score 1):

For American English speakers, with "standard" accents (say, mid-Atlantic, Midwestern), the voicing or silencing of the "a" can vary for the words in the question.

As an offbeat example, in the song "Doin' What Comes Natur'lly" from the musical "Annie Get Your Gun". The "a" is left out as an effect of a strong rural accent and to match the rhythm of the melody.

If you were being careful to fully enunciate the word "naturally," a speaker would pronounce the "a" ("nat-ur-ally"). If you were speaking quickly, casually, or with an accent in some regions, the "a" would not be distinguished ("nat-ur-ly"). The same is true for logically (log-ic-ly), "musically" (mu-sic-ly) and similar words.

Comment: I don't generally voice them, so I frequently have to check a dictionary to tell whether the word should be spelled "-ly" or "-ally"